# jquery sliding from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/3/** I want the slider not come from left side, but it must open itself from top. How to do this?

```
$("button" ).click(function() {
    $('.login').toggle('slide', {  duration: 1000,   easing: 'easeOutBounce', 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and quite easy to achieve, using `direction: 'up'`.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('.login').toggle('slide', {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        direction: 'up'
    });
});
```

[**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/Hx65Q/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code.

```
$("button" ).click(function() {
    $('.login').slideToggle( {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeOutBounce', 
});
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/9/)**

Comment: thank you. However I will select other guy as best answer because he was first.